# AWS cloud formation glue table reusable template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I have a lot of resources type `AWS::Glue::Table` in my aws templates. And I do not wont to copy-paste snippet of code from template to template. So idea is to create a reusable nested stack that accepts the params. I did it but one problem is still remaining. I do not know how I can pass columns via params to this stack `[{Type: string, Name: type}, {Type: string, Name: timeLogged}]` - it is an array of objects. But params accepts an only string type.

I tried to do something like this:
`!Split [ "," , "{Type: string, Name: type}, {Type: string, Name: timeLogged}"]` - but its did not helped

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: The AWS CloudFormation template for creating a Glue table
Parameters:
  DestinationBucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: Destination Regional Bucket Name
  DestinationBucketPrefix:
    Type: String
    Description: Destination Regional Bucket Prefix
  DatabaseName:
    Type: String
    Description: Database for Kinesis Analytics
  TableName:
    Type: String
    Description: Table for Kinesis Analytics
  InputFormat:
    Type: String
    Description: Input format for data
  OutputFormat:
    Type: String
    Description: Output format for data
  SerializationLibrary:
    Type: String
    Description: Serialization library for converting data

Resources:
  LogsCollectionTable:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Table
    Properties:
      DatabaseName: !Ref DatabaseName
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      TableInput:
        Name: !Ref TableName
        Description: Table for storing data
        TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE
        StorageDescriptor:
          Columns: [{Type: string, Name: type}, {Type: string, Name: timeLogged}]
          Location: !Sub s3://${DestinationBucketName}/${DestinationBucketPrefix}
          InputFormat: !Ref InputFormat
          OutputFormat: !Ref OutputFormat
          SerdeInfo:
            SerializationLibrary: !Ref SerializationLibrary
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You currently can not. You would need to pass every parameter manually.

[image]

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-parameters)